# How to use an Objective-C based framework in Swift based project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an Objective-C based cocoa pod framework. This framework has a class with XIP view controller. I want to access this controller from a Swift based project. The below code is Objective-C code. I need to use it in a Swift based project.

```
ViewController * viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@“VController” bundle:nil];
viewController.delegate = self;
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[vc presentViewController: viewController animated:true completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple just follow some steps and you are able to do That

I have a project and I am using RIOInterface.h Obj-c in My swift project

**Step 1-** Just add Objective c file in Swift Project

I added RIOinterface.h and .mm in my project

[image]

**Step 2** After when you will just drag and drop Obj-c Classes Now a popup will show as

[image]

-> Click Yes

**Step 3-** Now Import your Obj-C Header in bridging class created

[image]

**Step 4-** You are done with configuration steps Now, Time to use that class

as, I created a Object for that class

[image]

Now use it with that created object as below

[image]

**You accessed your objective-C code in Swift**